# Static variable across templated function compilations

Tags: c++

When creating a templated function, each template is its own independent version. As such, the static variables will only be static with respect to the function that calls it.

What are some efficient ways to get around this while still keeping that data private to the function, especially for a function in a header/inlined function?

I was thinking something along these lines, but it's private to the file then:

```
namespace
{
    unsigned char none;
}

template< typename t > unsigned char foo( )
{
    return none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following strategy:

1. Call a regular function in the implementation of the function template.
2. Store the data as a static variable in the regular function.

Something along the lines of:

```
unsigned char foo_impl()
{
   static unsigned char none = <some initializer>;
   return none;
}

template< typename t > unsigned char foo( )
{
    return foo_impl();
}
```

You can implement `foo_impl` in a source file instead of a header file in case there is a need to encapsulate its implementation.

Comment: I suppose this is a good solution, assuming that the implementation of each of `foo` has something in common. Something to consider, +1. Will mark as answer if nothing else is posted.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, I would recommend `inline` variable, so you can keep it in header and avoid duplicate symbols:

```
inline class cfoo_internal {
    unsigned char none /* = initialize */;
    template< typename t > friend unsigned char foo();
} foo_internal;

template< typename t > unsigned char foo( )
{
    return foo_internal.none;
}
```

Comment: But then the symbol is accessible outside of the function :/

Comment: @CryptographyMan Then wrap it in a class as private member, use friendship. However, if you use the function approach, it's still accessible from outside.

Comment: If i were to wrap it in a class, I could declare the variable and the function static (or have the class handled by a singleton), and set the member as private; friendship isn't necessary. While this is a better solution to the anonymous namespace one I put in the question, it's still not ideal.

Comment: @CryptographyMan `static` doesn't prevent access from the same translation unit. This is in a header file, others can still access.